# FB.ui share_open_graph giving wrong reponse on mobile

Tags: javascript, facebook, fb.ui, share-open-graph

My coding as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="1665615247095212" /> 
    <meta property="og:type" content="heppiheppi:shares" /> 
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://mywebsite.com" /> 
    <meta property="og:title" content="Walk-in" /> 
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://mywebsite.com/images/intro.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Bring more customers" />
</head>
<body style='padding:0;margin:0;'>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
        FB.init({
              appId      : '1665615247095212',
              xfbml      : true,
              version    : 'v2.7'
            });

            function LaunchDialog(){
            FB.ui({
               method: 'share_open_graph',
               action_type: 'og.shares',
               action_properties: JSON.stringify({
                 object:'http://mywebsite.com',
               })
             },
             function(response) {
if (response && !response.error_message) {
  alert('Posting completed.');
} else {
  alert('Error while posting.');
}
});
        }
    </script>
    <a href="#" onclick="LaunchDialog();">Share now</a>
</body>
</html>
```

If test on desktop browser, click "Share now", prompt the share dialog, click cancel/X, it will displays 'Error while posting.'
If test on mobile browser, click "Share now", prompt the share dialog, click cancel/X, it will displays 'Posting completed.'
Does anyone has any clue on this issue?

Comment: Check what the response object actually contains.

Comment: May I know how to check?

Comment: I use console.log to check the response object. If test on desktop browser, click Post to Facebook, it will displays nothing; click cancel/X, it will displays 'undefined'.

Comment: Are you logged in to Facebook on the mobile device? (In the browser, not any native app.)

Answer (score 0):

You set og:type to "heppiheppi:shares", have you created this Object type in your App !?? If it's not, set it back to "website".

Comment: I changed to <meta property="og:type" content="website" />, result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook team has confirmed this as a bug and assign this to the relevant team to investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

Update from Facebook:

The sharing team have investigated in detail and determined that the discrepancy is due to the different code paths on our side for the mobile and desktop version of the dialog

When you receive a post ID or error message in the response object, it should be as documented if the user has logged into  your app and/or has granted publish_actions permission

For all other cases, we don't document what the response will be, and the discrepancy you're encountering is that sometimes you receive an empty 'response' object and other times there's no response object at all

At this time it's not planned to make any changes to resolve this, and you cannot use the lack of response from the dialog to make any determination about whether a post was created

Apologies for the delay in getting a definite answer here, but you should assume that the current behaviour will remain in the short to medium term;

If long term changes are made, I think it's more likely that the response will be removed completely as that would be consistent with the other changes in this area to prevent share gating and other incentivization of users posts.